# Multiple Regression with Interaction

Tags: r, linear-regression, interaction

I've come across somewhat of a confusing topic relating to the syntax of multiple regression with explanatory variables and their interactions. A DataCamp explanation led me to think that:

`lm(formula = y ~ r + r:s , data)`

...is the same as:

`lm(formula = y ~ r + s + r:s , data)`

Which is incorrect. I have found that the latter is in fact the same as the shortened version:

`lm(formula = y ~ r * s , data)`

But the former is certainly different.

What exactly is the difference between these - that is, what does the first model show that the latter two wouldn't?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

### Simple Regression:

It is a subtle difference, but there is certainly a difference there. One way you can easily visualize the differences is by using the `summary` command. I will use the `iris` dataset since its already in R. First, a simple linear regression:

```
# Simple regression:
summary(lm(formula = Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length,
           data = iris))
```

This will just show the **one independent variable**, Sepal.Length, on the dependent variable, Sepal.Width:

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   3.41895    0.25356   13.48   <2e-16 ***
Sepal.Length -0.06188    0.04297   -1.44    0.152
```

### Interaction and Main Effects

For the next equation with just the `*` input:

```
# Interaction and main effects:
summary(lm(formula = Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length*Petal.Length,
           data = iris))
```

It gives us both the **main effects** of each independent variable/predictor, while also giving us the **interaction** between the two. You can see them all listed under coefficients now:

```
Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                1.51011    0.64336   2.347 0.020257 *  
Sepal.Length               0.46940    0.12954   3.624 0.000400 ***
Petal.Length              -0.42907    0.11832  -3.626 0.000397 ***
Sepal.Length:Petal.Length  0.01795    0.02186   0.821 0.413063
```

### Only Interaction

For the `:` input, it gives us **only the interaction** and nothing else:

```
# Only interaction:
summary(lm(formula = Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length:Petal.Length,
           data = iris))
```

Which you can see below:

```
Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                3.31473    0.06852  48.375  < 2e-16 ***
Sepal.Length:Petal.Length -0.01108    0.00257  -4.312 2.93e-05 ***
```

### Manually Adding Both Interactions and Effects

Finally, if you are entering **interactions** AND **manually adding main effects**, you would simply use the `:` input again, but then use `+` to add a main effect:

```
# Only interaction and one main effect:
summary(lm(formula = Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Length:Petal.Length,
           data = iris))
```

As seen below:

```
Coefficients:
                           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)               -0.299034   0.422673  -0.707     0.48    
Sepal.Length               0.807410   0.093603   8.626 9.44e-15 ***
Sepal.Length:Petal.Length -0.058626   0.005899  -9.939  < 2e-16 ***
```

Notice when I do the same call of using `+` and `*` now, it still just gives both the interaction and main effects without specifying.

```
summary(lm(formula = Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Length*Petal.Length,
           data = iris))
```

In a sense it actually ignores the plus sign:

```
Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                1.51011    0.64336   2.347 0.020257 *  
Sepal.Length               0.46940    0.12954   3.624 0.000400 ***
Petal.Length              -0.42907    0.11832  -3.626 0.000397 ***
Sepal.Length:Petal.Length  0.01795    0.02186   0.821 0.413063
```