# How to add the interaction term between dummies and continuous variable?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, data-analysis, coefficients

I want to include university-specific linear time trends in the following regression.

The data is like this:

| unitid | year |
| --- | --- |
| 100654 | 1991 |
| 100654 | 1992 |
| 100654 | 1993 |

```
model <- plm(gradrate4yr ~ block1 + block2 + instatetuition + faculty + costs 
       + per_urm + per_white + per_fem + as.factor(unitid) + as.factor(year), data = gradeData, 
            model = 'within', weights = meansize)
```

I've tried these - `year * unitid`, and also `unitid:year` , both of them are likely not the right way.

```
model <- plm(gradrate4yr ~ year * unitid + block1 + block2 + instatetuition + faculty + costs 
            + per_urm + per_white + per_fem + as.factor(unitid) + as.factor(year), data = gradeData, 
            model = 'within', weights = meansize)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Regression with Interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71166010/multiple-regression-with-interaction)

Comment: Why are they *"not the right way"*?

Comment: If you have panel data with N units and T periods, the interaction of time and unit factors will leave you with no degrees of freedom, because the interaction alone has as many parameters as you have observations

Comment: I just tested this. When you interact a factor or character variable with a continuous variable in plm, it appears to force the continuous variable to factor. Very strange. This seems like a bug. You might want to use `lm()` or another package like `lfe`